# On creating new dictionaries in python: Using for_loops vs using deepcopy()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just learnt how to build a dictionary out of another dictionary by using a for-loop.

But i can achieve the same using a deep-copy function. And `deep-copy()` seems to save time and is shorter.

Is there any disadvantage in using deep-copy.

Comment: It depends: What does your dictionary contain? Any mutable values?

Comment: Well it does contain mutable  values.

Comment: here it is : mydict =  {'bed length': '2 foot long', 'bed price': '800 pounds'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep copy is functionally different from using a for loop, which gives a shallow copy. If a dictionary contains any mutable objects, for example, lists, as values, then changing an element in a list changes the corresponding element in a shallow copy, but not in deep:

```
dic = {'1': [0, 1]}
shallow_copy = dic.copy()
from copy import deepcopy
deep_copy = deepcopy(dic)
dic['1'][0] = 1
shallow_copy
> {'1': [1, 1]}
deep_copy
> {'1': [0, 1]}
```

(Creating a copy dict via cycle gives essentially the same as dic.copy()) Of course, deep copy is generally slower, because it needs to copy all the elements at all levels of nesting, but in some cases you really want that change of a mutable element in the initial dict doesn't affect the copy - then use deepcopy. If all the values in the dict are immutable, there is no difference.

UPD: (Seeing your comments) Note that strings are immutable in Python.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; Use `copy.deepcopy` if you know there are mutable values or if you can't exclude that possibility. If it never contains mutable values just use the `dict.copy` method.

---

I previously commented to ask if the `dict` contained any mutable values. Let me explain that question:

If you have no mutable values (so only strings, numbers, tuples, frozensets, etc.) then just use the `.copy` method because a shallow copy is *enough*:

```
dct = {1: 1, 'a': 'a')
dct_copy = dct.copy()
```

or pass it to the `dict` function:

```
dct_copy = dict(dct)
```

However if your dictionary contains mutable values then don't use `for-loops` because `copy.deepcopy` is always faster and takes care of recursive data-structures and nested values:

```
dct = {1: [1,2,3,4], 2: [[1,2],[2,3]]}
from copy import deepcopy
dct_copy = deepcopy(dct)
```

With loops you might end up not deepcopying everything.

Comment: I get what you mean. But in what situations should i use for-loops rather than deep copy?

Comment: If you need some behaviour that isn't covered by `copy.deepcopy`. For example if you only want to shallow copy your values instead of recursing into these values: `{key, copy.copy(value) for key, value in your_dict.items()}`. That's a one-level-deep deepcopy. It really depends on what for-loop behaviour you have or want.